# How to accept List<String> as parameter in apex function call?

Tags: apex, batch

I have a method in ConnectedApiHelper class :

```
public static ConnectApi.BatchResult[] Gaurav2(String communityId, String subjectId,  ArrayList<String> textWithMentions) {
        //ConnectApi.BatchResult[] result = new ConnectApi.BatchResult[];
        List<ConnectApi.BatchInput> batchInputs = new List<ConnectApi.BatchInput>{};


        return  (new ConnectApi.BatchResult[]()) ;

    }
```

and I am calling it from developer console :

```
List<String> arr =  new List<String>();
arr.add('Hey {00536000002DqEu} , Gaurav1?');
arr.add('Hey {00536000002DqEu} , Gaurav2?');


ConnectApi.BatchResult[] rs =   ConnectApiHelper.Gaurav2('0DB36000000TNuDGAW','me',arr);
```

But its giving me error :

[image]

Comment: check return type its ConnectApi.BatchResult[] for Gaurav2 method.

Answer (score 4):

You function returns a `ConnectApi.BatchResult[]` variable.

And you're trying to get a `String` variable as result.

Just replace:

```
ConnectApi.BatchResult[] rs = ConnectApiHelper.Gaurav2('0DB36000000TNuDGAW','me',arr);
```

**Update**

Here's a great [tutorial](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex) to learn basic Apex. If you think you need it.

ps:dedicace to @RahulSharma :D

Comment: Maybe it would be also helpful for others if you can add link to documentation :)

Comment: A documentation link for: "How to get a variable as a result of a function"? :D

Comment: Yeah, sound silly, but then we still have a question asked here :D